# Java - getConstructor()?

Tags: java, reflection, getconstructor

I wrote the question as a comment in the code, I think its easier to understand this way.

```
public class Xpto{
    protected AbstractClass x;

    public void foo(){

       // AbstractClass y = new ????? Car or Person ?????

       /* here I need a new object of this.x's type (which could be Car or Person)
          I know that with x.getClass() I get the x's Class (which will be Car or 
          Person), however Im wondering how can I get and USE it's contructor */

       // ... more operations (which depend on y's type)
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractClass {
}

public class Car extends AbstractClass{
}

public class Person extends AbstractClass{
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to learn reflection, or is this a part of your application? If latter, there are better and safer alternatives for constructing an object of desired type at runtime, e.g. factories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, BalusC is right.

Secondly:

If you're taking decisions based on the class type, you're not letting the polymorphism do its job.

Your class structure may be  wrong ( Like Car and Person should not be in the same hierarchy )

You could probably create an interface and code to it.

```
interface Fooable {
     Fooable createInstance();
     void doFoo();
     void doBar();
}

class Car implements Fooable {
     public Fooable createInstance() {
          return new Car();
     }
     public void doFoo(){
         out.println("Brroooom, brooooom");
     }
     public void doBar() {
          out.println("Schreeeeeeeekkkkkt");
      }
}
class Person implements Fooable {
     public Fooable createInstance(){   
         return new Person();
      }
      public void foo() {
           out.println("ehem, good morning sir");
      }
      public void bar() {
          out.println("Among the nations as among the individuals, the respect for the other rights means peace..");// sort of 
      }
}
```

Later ...

```
public class Xpto{
    protected Fooable x;

    public void foo(){
         Fooable y = x.createInstance();
         // no more operations that depend on y's type.
         // let polymorphism take charge.
         y.foo();
         x.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I agree with using a factory method to create new instances. It's a bit like `clone`, only that it returns a blank instead of a copy.

Comment: @Chris: Yeap, clone could be used also, when you don't know anything about the object until runtime ( which is rate in Java, there you know at least it's some type of Fooable ) but when you have: `Object o = ???; Object copy = o.clone()` could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, because `Object.clone` is protected, the only way you can do that with objects of unknown type is to invoke `clone` by reflection. :-P And if you're gonna use reflection, you may as well reflect on the factory method, or even the constructor. :-P

Comment: @Chris: But the type is partially know. It is a Fooable/AbstractClass, which can redefine clone() as public.

Answer (score 3):

If the class has a (implicit) default no-arg constructor, then you can just call [`Class#newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). If you want to obtain a specific constructor, then use [`Class#getConstructor()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) wherein you pass the parametertypes to and then call [`Constructor#newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) on it. *The code in blue are actually links, click them to get the Javadoc, it contains detailed explanation about what exactly the method does.*

To learn more about reflection, head to the [Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html).